# a4j:ajax listener does not fire for empty input

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, listener

I have the following code:

```
<h:inputText id="test-id" class="test-class"
                            value="#{testBean.value}">
    <a4j:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.testMethod()}" execute="@this"/>
</h:inputText>
```

The method `testMethod()` only gets called when there is a value on the input field i.e. changing the value of the input field to a non-empty value. But if I remove the value i.e. deleting the value on the input field and leaving the box empty, `testMethod()` does not fire. Now I get this is due to validation.

I have tried adding `immediate=true` to the `a4j:ajax`, and the method does get called this way when there's a change in input (even going from having a value to being empty), but there's an issue. If the box goes from having a value to being empty, on the backing bean `testBean.value` it still has the previous value before being empty. And after this let's say I add a value to the input box, so it goes from being empty to having a value, `testBean.value` is empty. So it's always a step behind.

What can I do so the method gets called when going from having a value to being empty and viceversa and have 'testBean.value` on the backing bean contain the latest inputted value?

Comment: Have you tried the keyup event?

Comment: Yes, I did. Same issue. I had to use javascript, and through javascript call a java method (using a jsf button with an action that gets clicked using jquery on keyup) but I find it odd that jsf does not provide a way to do this. I'm sure there is one, I'm just not aware of it.